# Is it OK to cast undefined to void in TS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, void, void-safety

## TLDR;

#### Is this OK? Or is it bad practice?

```
function isUndefined (payload: any): payload is undefined | void {
  return payload === undefined
}
```

## Context

In TypeScript, I have a function that can return either something or `undefined` or `void`.

Something like an event handler that can return a modified payload or the dev can choose to return nothing or undefined in case they won't modify the payload:

```
function eventHandler <T extends {[key: string]: any}> (payload: T): Modified<T> | undefined | void {
  // ... implementation
}
```

Then I have a type checker that needs to check if it's returning something other than void or undefined:

```
const result = eventHandler(payload)

if (result !== undefined) {
  // we have a modified payload!
}
```

However, is the above snippet I get an error because it says that even though `result !== undefined` it can still be `void`?

In my opinion, I think it's peculiar because `void` should be the same as `undefined`.

So I made this type checker that solves it:

```
function isUndefined (payload: any): payload is undefined | void {
  return payload === undefined
}
```

This solves my issue, but my question is:

Is this OK? Or is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void` is not `undefined`. `void` means the absence of a return value. `undefined` is the type of the value undefined at runtime.

it is true that a function that returns no value at run time returns `undefined`, but in the TS type system we chose to make the absence of a return value special.

For example assigning `(a) => void to (a) => number | undefined` is likely an error, though it is safe at run-time.

In general do not use void except in the return type of functions. for everything else, use `undefined`.

So, yes we will need to use different check for `undefined` and `void`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're making this more complicated that it needs to be. A function that returns `void` can:

1. Have no return statement
2. Have a `return;` statement with no value specified.
3. Have a `return undefined;` statement.

In pure javascript, all of the above would have a return value of `undefined`. If you say a function returns `undefined`, then you can only do #2 and #3 from the above list.

So you can just have a function type that unions `void` with whatever *something* you want.

```
function foo(): string | void {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'abc' : 123
}

const val = foo()
if (val === undefined) {
    console.log('is undefined', val)
} else {
    console.log('is some value', val)
}
```

---

This means that you could create a generic function type that modifies payloads like so:

```
type PayloadModifier<T extends {[key: string]: any}> = (payload: T) => T | void

const setMaxAsTen: PayloadModifier<{a: number}> = (payload) => {
    if (payload.a > 10) {
        return { a: 10 }
    }
    return undefined // required unless noImplicitReturns is false
}

const val = setMaxAsTen({a: 5})
if (val === undefined) {
    console.log('is undefined', val)
} else {
    console.log('is some value', val)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghiANgezgEwLLLQSwGY4QBOAPACpQQAewEAdmgM5QDeA2gNYQgBcUjwIjjoBzALp84dEAF8AfFAC8UABRgEKdHzIBKJQooAfKADdkONAChLAY2R0B-CMAxwqAQUZl6feElSY2PiEpCxwfHQArgC2AEbE8kqq6v7oeooKLJZQOVD4yRoBAHRwUAoAjAAMelm5dVBEzpFEdKxQ4VBVUDLZuT11jcDNrZEMEAR0EGhQAPQzDRAAjpE4jdOjiBCMzHTIAJLRYIg4NjjAAEpNLcw4zHhwiIwQlj229o4mD0lPLm6e3nQVGE+ABWGQ6Sz5FSfRBKRTKUZocbCKY1Xo5OwOZCbIooEQqADktygiORkzQBIANKYHhCZJRHtBarlMYxsRBcch8UTmGzotAYZEIFSaYg6UA)

Last thing to note is that there is a compiler option that is good to leave on [called `noImplicitReturns`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html). if a function declares a return value in any execution branch, then a return value must be declared in every execution branch. So because the above sometimes returns a value, you must explicitly return `undefined` if you don't to return a payload. You can toggle off that option, allowing you to omit that line, but it's not recommended as it does help you catch some bugs.